# What Types of properties can be set directly in declarative markup (as attributes)?

Tags: types, properties, user-controls, declarative

I understand that whenever you create a property for a user control, you can set the property value through declarative syntax, so you can have something like this:

```
<uc1:MyControl id="MyControl1" runat="server" Text="Hello" Number="10" Access="ReadWrite" />
```

These attributes set the value for properties of type:

- Text is String
- Number is Integer
- Access is Enum

I wouldn't be able to set a public property of type "Array" or "Control" in declarative markup. (or can I?)

My question is:

**What is the complete list of Types that can be set directly with declarative syntax as attributes in a control?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some time with this question without being solved, finally I found the official answer in this [article at the MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s.aspx#Y900).

Turns out that those properties that can be persisted as attributes are called **Simple Properties** and must be a string or a type that easily maps to a string. Here's an extract of the article:

> " A simple property is a property whose type is a string or a type that
>   maps easily to a string. A simple property is persisted as an
>   attribute on the control's opening tag without any work on your part.
>   Properties of type String and primitive value types in the .NET
>   Framework class library such as Boolean, Int16, Int32, and Enum are
>   simple properties. "

So I had the list almost complete in my question. Properties that can be set directly with declarative syntax (as atributes) must be of the following types:

- String
- Boolean
- Int16
- Int32
- Enum